# iOS Auto layout problems with spacing

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to place `UIImage`, `UITextView` and `UIView` one after another vertically.

I've set all constraints and spaces between views. But it says that it need constraints for Y position or height for `UIView` and `UITextView`.

**What have I done wrong?**

Here is screenshot: http://s019.radikal.ru/i616/1509/63/f18ed2a349f3.png

Comment: Autolayout sometimes goes crazy with TextView if its scrolling is enabled.

Comment: Set a height constraint on your `textView`

Comment: Cant you just set the height constraints...if you have already set it....then pls update the question...specifying the constraints you have set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally these problems arise from putting a UIImageView itself with constraints. Your best bet is to put in a view and embed the image inside the view. This should make your life a lot easier. Just reset constraints and then click add missing constraints on the whole controller. :-)